# How to get in the file name in minifilter

Tags: c, kernel-module, minifilter

I'm trying to create a driver that gets the file name, I even got it with an example: `DbgPrint("%ws", &FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer);`

But how do I get the file name without `"%ws"`? Only with a `DbgPrint(&FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer);`?

When I try to call the function without `"%ws"`, the minifilter returns `"\"`, could someone help me please?

This is my code:

```
PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileNameInfo;
    NTSTATUS Status;

    Status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data,
        FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT,
        &FileNameInfo);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(Status))
    {
        Status = FltParseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);

        if (NT_SUCCESS(Status))
        {
            DbgPrint(&FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer);
        }

        FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
```

I'm using google translator.

Comment: at first use `"%ws"` is wrong. `Name.Buffer` is not 0-terminating string (can be or can not be, undefined). need use `%wZ` format for print `UNICODE_STRING`. at second *But how do I get the file name without...* - how understand this ?

Comment: I would like to get the file name without the `"%wZ"`, because I want to compare it with a string that I read in a file, for example:

The minifilter reads the file (which contains files and folders to be blocked, using `ZwReadFile`), so how do I compare if the `FileNameInfo` value contains what the `ZwReadFile` returned? is there any way to use `"%wZ"` other than in `DbgPrint`? like, `strstr`?

Comment: what you mean under **get** file name ?

Comment: When I use: `DbgPrint(FileName Info->Name.Buffer)`, the mini filter returns `"\"`, but when I use: `DbgPrint("%wZ", FileName Info->Name.Buffer)`, it returns the correct file name , how do I get the file name without using `%wZ`? How do I convert that `"\"` to the file path? or how to make a comparison if string using `%wZ`? Could you help me, please?